# Azure blob storage overwriting duplicate files

Tags: azure, blob, storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob storage to upload/download files. The problem is, if I upload any new file to azure blob that have the same name as already uploaded file then its automatically overwriting the content of previously uploaded file.

**For example**

These are the files uploaded on azure blob storage -

1. file1.docx
2. file2.png
3. file1.png

So if i am uploading a new file named as "file1.docx" which have the different content. Then blob storage is replacing the previous uploaded file1.docx . So in this case i am losing the previously uploaded file.

Is there any way that blob storage can automatically detect that there is duplicate so it can append _1 or (1) in the end or any other way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way that blob storage can automatically detect that there
> is duplicate so it can append _1 or (1) in the end or any other way to
> solve this problem ?

Out of the box this feature is not available and you will have to handle this in your application. If your upload operation fails with a `Conflict (HTTP Status Code 409)` error that would mean that a blob by the name of the uploaded file exists. You would then need to retry the operation by appending `_1` or `(1)`. You will need to keep on doing it by increasing the counter till the time your upload does not fail with conflict status code.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, I was also thinking to do that. Just wanted to make sure that this is the only solution.

Comment: If you just want to keep read-only copies of the document what you can do is take a snapshot of the original blob before overwriting it. But if you want to keep them as separate files then I believe this is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also append GUID to your file name which will make the file unique.